# SharePoint hosted App permission

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-addin, publishing, app

I deployed a SharePoint hosted app. Can Someone explain to me the permission scope *Web*?

My app has to create lists and items on the site. Which *permission* do I need?

If I want to publish the App on the Store I can not use *full-control* permission as says this article
[Validation policies for the apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission Scope `Web` will allow you to work with Host web site. Suppose you have a site collection at url `http://sitename`. And under it you have a sub site `http://sitename/subsite`. Now you deploy an app in the subsite. So the subsite will be the Host web. Now you want to create a list in subsite so you will need to provide  `Web` Scope. However, if you want to create a list in `http://sitename` you will need to give `Site Collection` scope. However, if you are directly deploying the app under root site collection and just want to create a list in Host Web, then `Web` Scope is sufficient. Secondly, `Manage` permissions are enough to create a list in Host Web. Lastly, Microsoft won't allow `Full Control` permission based apps because of data security issues. It is like saying give my app permissions to mess with your data.

Comment: But if I ceate a list inside an app does not it live inside the app? If yes I do not need any permission on the web site.

Comment: Yes, the permissions are only needed if you want to create a list inside Host Web. However, if you want to create a list in App Web, then there is no need to give permissions. See this for more info: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-create-sharepoint.html and this http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-apps-access-data-in.html

Comment: And to create a group? Do I need Full-Control on the site?

Comment: Yes Scope should be site collection and permission should be Full Control